# Button falling outside of div with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align my button in the bottom right corner on the paragraph. Trying to position it with secondary selector. What is the best way to push this element to the bottom of its container? And how do I make sure it stays inside of it

HTML is just a `img` and a paragraph. Is there a better way to wrap the text into a box than just styling the paragraph and putting a button inside?

```css
.primary {
  /*    visibility: hidden;*/
  width: 300px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.secondary {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: tomato;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  border-top: 20px solid #3B3B3B;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}


/*

flexbox stuff
*/

.secondary {
  /*    should style the button?*/
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .primary {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Show image and text stacked between 769px : 960px*/

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}


/*Image and text side by side when screen > 960px*/

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item primary">
      <img class="item primary" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="item secondary">The paragraph
        <div class="button-cnt">
          <button class="btn">Go</button>
        </div>

      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have added the answer. `.secondary{flex-direction...}` but `secondary` is not flex container. Please study flex before applying it.   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/